# Number of solutions for $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i = 1}^k a_i = n$

Tags: combinatorics

I am aware that number of solutions for $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ for
$$a_1+a_2+...+a_k = n$$ is $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$

For $n = 3$ or $n = 2$, it is easy to make cases and follow the result. But

**How to derive this result for arbitrary n and k?**

Comment: Look at the [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) article in Wikipedia. it is pretty good.  There have also been good explanations on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Man, of all the nicknames they could have given that technique, they had to choose that one.